# Weird edit approvals?

Tags: discussion

https://serverfault.com/posts/362856/revisions

Maybe I'm just being picky here, but I don't think it was great this edit was approved.

- NTP doesn't actually support changing the port number, so the comment about that is useless
- The monlist command was indeed removed in later versions, but including configuration suggestions here seems pretty out of scope.

The sentence structure here is a bit odd now as well.

Am I just being too picky because this was an edit of one of my posts?

Comment: You're not being nit-picky at all, those edits just make the answer less clear. In the future just roll back, and come to meta if the edits persist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think you are being too picky especially if the edit is partially incorrect. As the original author you do not have to accept the edit even though it has been approved by 2 other people. You can simply go to the revision that you prefer and click rollback - that's what I would do here. There is even a badge for [rollback](https://serverfault.com/help/badges/4/cleanup).

[image: There is even a badge for this]

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't have approved this edit, as it changes too much of the meaning of the post, something editors are supposed to avoid. I can't speak to what the reviewers were thinking.

As the post author, you are free to rollback the edit or improve it further.